# Нагрузка Префабов на Сцену. Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть сцена, для этой сцены есть 50 уровней, загруженных в префабы. Эти префабы закинуты в главный скрипт сцены, который висит на камере. При заргрузке сцены появляется определённый уровень через Instantiate. У меня происходит зависание игры через 10-15 мин после её начала на телефоне, падает фпс, и просто сильно неимоверно всё залагивает.

Верно ли я понимаю, что при каждой загрузке сцены, эти 50 префабов также подгружаются каждый раз, т.к. они упомянуты в скрипте, который висит на объекте сцены? И это каждый раз нагружает сильно игру? Если да, то как верно в этом случае загружать уровень на сцену?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если следовать простому подходу "1 сцена = 1 уровень" такой проблемы возникать не должно в принципе.

А дальше по мере необходимости асинхронно загружаешь другую сцену с экраном загрузки(или вообще без него!) и никаких проблем быть не должно.

А загружать уровень из префаба полностью звучит совсем не оптимально. Плюс неясно дестроишь ли ты обьект старого уровня.

Так же неясно что такое уровень. Может это пара легких обьектов, а может это огроменный тяжелейший набор обьектов занимающий половину оперативки.

---

Теперь по поводу тормозов - тормоза начинаются через 15 минут времени. Что бы я не предположил - очень высока вероятность ошибится. Это может быть мемори лик, например. Или перегрев телефона + тротлинг из-за неоптимально написанного кода. Или еще что.

## Это необходимо выяснять через использование профайлера и никак иначе.

Не нужно гадать на кофейной гуще. Нужно сесть и посмотреть в чем конкретно проблема.

Comment: По поводу "1 сцена = 1 уровень" я думал об этом, что это исправит ошибку эту. Но я посчитал это не оптимальным вариантом, потому что фон сцены всегда один и расположение UI тоже, меняется только расположение объектов на сцене, поэтому целесообразно каждый уровень держать в Prefab. Просто иначе если я захочу на одной сцене допустим поменять освещение, то на 49 других также придется это все делать. От Destroy объектов везде избавился))) Теперь их просто SetActive, потому что почитал где-то, что Destroy - это вредно.

Comment: Идея 1го комментатора я к ней склоняюсь, что она как-то может помочь решить эту проблему, но надо протестить её, чем и буду заниматься в ближайшее время. Зато из-за этого бага за 2 месяца изучил многое по системе оптимизации игры, уменьшив файл игры с 45 мб до 25, но главный баг заедание так и не исправил. Вот теперь буду Resources.Load разбираться. Буду разбираться, Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Destroy использовать это хорошо. Для чего тебе хранить в оперативе  то, что тебе не понадобится все оставшийся время игры? Плохо использовать дестрой на куче обьектов в короткий промежуток времени. И тем более там где можно переиспользовать заново - например на пулях - нету смысла инстанстиэейтить пулю а потом дестроить если ее можно просто переиспользовать заново по мере необходимости не нагружая железо. Вот там да - дестрой это плохо. Ну а если ты не будешь обьект переиспользовать - то храня ты просто стреляешь себе в ногу и вполне вероятно именно этим ты себе и засираешь память до тормозов.

Comment: "потому что фон сцены всегда один и расположение UI тоже, " - вместо "оптимизации" через загрузку лишних обьектов.... Необходимо просто НЕ ВЫГРУЖАТЬ нужные обьекты при загрузке второй сцены используя DontDestroyOnLoad ( https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html ). Это в разы лучше чем загружать в оперативку лишние обьекты и замусоривать память.

Comment: Собственно по тому что ты сейчас пишешь - очень вероятно что ты своими "оптимизациями" эти тормоза сам же и создаешь. Очень вероятно что ты себе забиваешь оперативу мусором который ты умышленно загружаешь в оперативу и по мере необходимости не очищаешь. Вот и тормоза. Но снова таки необходимо запустить профайлер и смотреть на него, а не гадать на кофейной гуще как делает в своем ответе Максим Фисман или как делаю сейчас я :)

Comment: Я понял вас, Спасибо))) Хотелось бы ещё такое предположение услышать, как лучше делать. Вот две сцены, одна состоит просто из UI уровней, сцена выбора уровня проще говоря. Вторая сцена это однотипная игровая сцена, на которой с каждым уровнем просто меняется расположение нескольких объектов. Игрок прошел допустим 1 уровень, дальше есть кнопка "Следующий уровень". Как целесообразнее или правильнее её использовать. 1. Отправлять игрока на предыдущую сцену с выбором уровней, чтобы он сам нажал на UI 2го уровеня и снова вернулся обратно на Игровую сцену со 2оым уже уровнем.

Comment: Либо 2. Удалить на сцене 10-15 объектов через Destroy 1го уровня и сразу же через Instantiate загрузить 10-15(один префаб) объектов 2го уровня.

Comment: Имхо целесообразнее вариант 3: после прохождения первого уровня загружать второй уровень сразу без возвращения на меню выбора уровней. Для чего юзера заставлять делать лишних несколько кликов? Что бы что? Это подход к интерфейсу прошлого столетия, так уже не делают очень давно)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по падению фпс, эти префабы действительно могут прогружаться при загрузке сцены, так как они проинициализированы в инспекторе. Точно сказать не могу, не нашел какой-то информации, но вообще это логично.

---

Чтобы избежать этого попробуйте положить префабы в папку Resources, пронумеровав так, чтобы можно было провести конкретную нуменклатуру. Если это уровни, это может быть `Level_1`, `Level_2`, `Level_3`... Вы можете в рантайме загружать файлы, лежащие в папке Resources: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

```
int levelIndex = 2;
GameObject prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Level_" + levelIndex);
Instantiate(prefab, ...);
```

---

Вы также можете рассмотреть вариант хранения уровней в виде, например, json-файлов и строить их "на месте" при загрузке уровня.

Если при загрузке уровня все же происходят задержки, то стоит сделать прогресс бар или вроде того.

Comment: а из чего делается вывод о том что они инициализированы в инспекторе? Фраза "Эти префабы закинуты в главный скрипт сцены, который висит на камере" означает лишь что они атачнуты в поля скрипта. Но никак не означает что они инициализированны. Может они инстантиэйтятся по ходу прохождения уровня, например. Кода-то не видно. Вобщем ответ строится на предположениях основаных на предположениях.

Comment: @Andrew Не совсем понял первое предложение. Под инициализацией в инспекторе я имел в виду как раз "акт нажимания на объект, и перемещения его в переменную в скрипте, удерживая ЛКМ". "Атачнуты" -- это судя по всему то же самое. Просто установили переменную через инспектор ("повесили, перетащили..."). Я предположил, что префабы грузятся, просто будучи закинутыми в инспектор. `ответ строится на предположениях` -- да, вы правы (см. 2-е предложение ответа). Я действительно не знаю, грузятся ли префабы сразу, если их просто указать в инспекторе, но сделал предположение с целью помочь автору вопроса.

Comment: Допустим они инстантиэйтятся по запуску уровня и причина тормозов именно в этом - почему тормоза начинаются через 15 минут а не сразу по запуску уровня?